# Deploy to HockeyApp fails

Tags: tfs, win-universal-app, azure-devops, automated-deploy, hockeyapp

I ran through [a tutorial on the HockeyApp site](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/third-party-bug-trackers-services-and-webhooks/how-to-use-hockeyapp-with-team-foundation-server-tfs-or-visual-studio-team-services-vsts) for creating and uploading the HockeyApp build Task to Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). When I queue a new build, it clones my repo from GitHub, builds it and publishes the artifacts.

When VSTS goes to execute my HockeyApp build task, it fails.

---

```
Files found locally 299,
Files evaluated 299,
Files left to evaluate 0.,
Files created without upload 0,
Files uploaded 297
Files left to process 2
---------------------------
Created 0 files without uploading content. Total files processed 299
Uploaded artifact 'C:\a\1\a\drop' to container folder 'drop' of build 42.
Associated artifact 13 with build 42
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: PublishBuildArtifacts
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Deploy /drop/Applications/OpenTasks.WindowsUWP/bin/x86/Debug/OpenTasks.exe to HockeyApp
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\HockeyApp\0.9.18\bootstrapper.ps1
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\HockeyApp\0.9.18\hockeyApp.js:216
throw new Error(errorMessage);
^
Error: Could not decode the hockey endpoint. Please ensure you are running the latest agent (min version 0.3.0)
at getEndpointDetails (C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\HockeyApp\0.9.18\hockeyApp.js:216:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\HockeyApp\0.9.18\hockeyApp.js:19:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: HockeyApp
******************************************************************************
Task HockeyApp failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
Worker Worker-c371305d-0d72-4f8b-b809-724a1a9316ea finished running job c371305d-0d72-4f8b-b809-724a1a9316ea
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
******************************************************************************
```

My project is structured like

```
Root
  - readme.md
  - Source
    - Applications
      - WindowsUWP
      - Mobile
        - iOS
        - Droid
      - Shared
  - Services
  - Domain
```

I'm able to build the project and see the artifacts get deployed

```
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.5\PublishBuildArtifacts.ps1
Preparing artifact content in staging folder C:\a\1\a...
Copying all files from C:\a\1\s\Source\Applications\OpenTasks.Shared\bin to C:\a\1\a\drop\Applications\OpenTasks.Shared\bin
Copying all files from C:\a\1\s\Source\Applications\OpenTasks.Shared.Tests\bin to C:\a\1\a\drop\Applications\OpenTasks.Shared.Tests\bin
Copying all files from C:\a\1\s\Source\Applications\OpenTasks.WindowsUWP\bin to C:\a\1\a\drop\Applications\OpenTasks.WindowsUWP\bin
Copying all files from C:\a\1\s\Source\CloudProviders\Provider.Dropbox\bin to C:\a\1\a\drop\CloudProviders\Provider.Dropbox\bin
Copying all files from C:\a\1\s\Source\Domain\DomainLogic\bin to C:\a\1\a\drop\Domain\DomainLogic\bin
Copying all files from C:\a\1\s\Source\Domain\DomainLogic.Tests\bin to C:\a\1\a\drop\Domain\DomainLogic.Tests\bin
Total files copied: 299.
```

In my VSTS build definition I have added the HockeyApp Task, and configured it using my HockeyApp API token and AppId from HockeyApp.

[image]

The Binary Path is set based on the output drop path, with \x86\debug\opentask.exe appended to it. I have tried using the following combinations (and more, but i can't remember them all at the moment)

```
/Source/Applications/OpenTasks.WindowsUWP
./
/drop
/Source
/drop/Applications/OpenTasks.WindowsUWP/bin
```

This is the output of my installation and upload of the HockeyApp Task.

[image]

I can't seem to get the app to deploy to HockeyApp.

I'm not sure if the real error is:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
```

or if that's a result of this error

```
Error: Could not decode the hockey endpoint. Please ensure you are running the latest agent (min version 0.3.0)
```

Eitherway, i'm not sure how to solve for it. I've give it my HockeyApp api token, and the app id, and tried a large number of different binary paths. I burned through 25% of my free builds on VSTS last night trying to get my builds to deploy. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

I am running the hosted build agent.

Answer (score 4):

Use **\* for Binary File Path, for example **\*.apk.

Another important thing is that, exe file format is not supported by HockeyApp. You may get 422 error when upload it. For the supported file type, refer to this link for details: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-create-a-new-app.

Comment: I'm confused tho, the .exe is what I'm given for a Windows UWP app. Does it generate two separate files with different extensions and I'm just missing the the right UWP extension?

Comment: When I compile the app, only a .exe is generated. I'm using Any CPU as my build config. Is there additional steps to get my UWP app to hockey?

Comment: UWP apps are packaged and distributed using AppX packaging format. Refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn726767.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It might help,

Set the ***Binary File Path*** to

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\OpenTasks.WindowsUWP_$(AppxVersion)_Test\OpenTasks.WindowsUWP_$(AppxVersion)_x86_x64_ARM.appxbundle
```

Answer (score 0):

The hockeyapp task that in your snapshot doesn't seem to correspond to the one from the extension, the new hockeyapp task from the extension expects a service endpoint and not Hockey API Token.

I guess you had uploaded the hockeyapp task, you can try using the extension now.

Answer (score 0):

did you get it to work using the extension?

I ran into the same issue regarding the binary path. I finally looked in the build step log file and found where the .appx package was placed. For my sample project, the build step put it here:

```
C:\a\1\s\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\bin\ARM\Release\x64\HelloWorld\HelloWorld_1.0.0.0_x64.appx
```

So I plugged this into the HockeyApp deploy step's Binary File Path parameter:

```
HelloWorld\HelloWorld\bin\ARM\Release\x64\HelloWorld\HelloWorld_1.0.0.0_x64.appx
```

It's not the neat and clean "$(variablename)\AppxPackages" format that the samples show, or anything even close to that. But it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I was never able to get it working. I will give your solution a shot though

Answer (score 0):

Yes this VSTS Task is really frustrating. Apparently, the Binary File it's referring to is the .appxbundle file.

[image: Example Binary File Path]

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem so I would like to show exact solution:

1. Go to "Artifacts" section in your build result and click "Explore" button:

[image]

2. Check the name of folder where you app packages are located. You should look for .appxbundle file extension:

[image]

3. Now go to HockeyApp build step and fill "Binary File Path":

[image]

Now it is working fine and I do not have to change "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" directory. Hope this will help you!